# extract everything after regex pattern in string

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the text after a date pattern in a string.
I'm able to match the date in regex but can't find a way to extract the whole text after.

Below is the string I'm working on.

```
tt1<-"Football\n/\n\nColombia\n\n/\nLiga Aguila 2019\n07 Dec 2019 - Clausura - Play Offs\n1\nX\n2\nB's\n\n22:00\n\nAmerica De Cali\n\n2\n2\n–\n0\n\nJunior\n\n0\n\n2.18\n\n2.99\n\n3.59\n\n9"
```

I'm able to extract the date using the following regex:

```
str_extract(tt1, "(\\d{2}\\s{1}\\w{3}\\s{1}\\d{4})")
"07 Dec 2019"
```

Now I want all the text after that pattern. So my desired output would be

```
" - Clausura - Play Offs\n1\nX\n2\nB's\n\n22:00\n\nAmerica De Cali\n\n2\n2\n–\n0\n\nJunior\n\n0\n\n2.18\n\n2.99\n\n3.59\n\n9"
```

By doing the following I'm able to extract some of the text after the pattern but not all of it. Also the date is still included in the output which is not the desired output.

```
str_extract(tt1, "(\\d{2}\\s{1}\\w{3}\\s{1}\\d{4}).*")
[1] "07 Dec 2019 - Clausura - Play Offs"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want/need to keep before, date, and after strings, you can use `strcapture`:

```r
out <- strcapture("(.*)\\s+(\\d{2}\\s{1}\\w{3}\\s{1}\\d{4})\\s+(.*)",
                  tt1, list(bef="",dt="",aft=""))
out
#                                              bef          dt                                                                                                                        aft
# 1 Football\n/\n\nColombia\n\n/\nLiga Aguila 2019 07 Dec 2019 - Clausura - Play Offs\n1\nX\n2\nB's\n\n22:00\n\nAmerica De Cali\n\n2\n2\n–\n0\n\nJunior\n\n0\n\n2.18\n\n2.99\n\n3.59\n\n9
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ bef: chr "Football\n/\n\nColombia\n\n/\nLiga Aguila 2019"
#  $ dt : chr "07 Dec 2019"
#  $ aft: chr "- Clausura - Play Offs\n1\nX\n2\nB's\n\n22:00\n\nAmerica De Cali\n\n2\n2\n–\n0\n\nJunior\n\n0\n\n2.18\n\n2.99\n\n3.59\n\n9"
```

You can choose to not include the `bef` section by removing the parens around the first regex group.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  What would be the regex to only capture everything after the date pattern using str_extract ? I've tried to use str_extract(tt1, "(\\d{2}\\s{1}\\w{3}\\s{1}\\d{4})\\s+(.+)")  but It still stops after "Play Offs"

Comment: `gsub(".*(\\d{2}\\s{1}\\w{3}\\s{1}\\d{4}\\s+.*)", "\\1", tt1)` combines `dt` and `aft` into one string. `str_extract` appears to not like the newlines.

Comment: Indeed there's a problem with the newlines in str_extract. The problem with the above is that I still have the date included in the output.  The output I'd like would begin after the date like this " - Clausura - Play Offs\n1\nX\n2\nB's\n\n22:00\n\nAmerica De Cali\n\n2\n2\n–\n0\n\nJunior\n\n0\n\n2.18\n\n2.99\n\n3.59\n\n9"

Comment: Using my first code, what you're asking for is literally `out$aft`. The `gsub` variant would be to _NOT_ collect (using parens) the date portion, as in `gsub(".*\\d{2}\\s{1}\\w{3}\\s{1}\\d{4}\\s+(.*)", "\\1", tt1)` (though we can use `sub` as well).